# Custom select menu issue (jquery and php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a dropdown menu that is being pulled from Wordpress admin with php.

```
$agg = "
<div class='select-aggr'>
    <h2 class='select-aggr-h'>
        I want to read about
    </h2>
        <select class='mounth'>
            <option value='hide'>
            <a href='$url' class='aggregator-option selected' data-name='everythings' data-filter='category-anything'>everything</a>
            </option>";
$query = "SELECT name FROM wp_terms t
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tx ON t.term_id = tx.term_id
    WHERE t.term_id in ($cats)
    AND tx.parent = 0
    AND tx.taxonomy in ($tax)";
$results = $wpdb->get_results ($query);

foreach ($results as $cat) {
    $name = $cat->name;
    if (strtolower($name) == "featured") {
        continue;
    }
    $agg .= '<option value="' .$name.'" >
        <a href="' .$url . '?cat=' . strtolower($name) .'" class="aggregator-option" data-name="'.$name.'" data-filter="category-'.$name.'">'.$name.'</a>
    </option>';
}
$agg .= "
    </select>
</div>";
```

The idea is that inside $agg the option  tag gets a whatever href and information pulled from wordpress.

Now I've created a jQuery function for the custom dropdown menu. So instead of Options it creates UL with LI corresponding to the options that got pulled. That way it makes it easy for me to style them however I want and create custom arrow, etc.

Now how do I add an  tag within those list items with the correct information? For some reason a few combinations I've tried don't work.

Here is the code for the jQuery function that I need help with

```
$('.mounth').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this), numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

                $this.addClass('select-hidden');
                $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
                $this.after('<div class="select-styled"></div>');

                    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.select-styled');
                $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

                    var $list = $('<ul />', {
                    'class': 'select-options'
                }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

                    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
                    $('<li />', {
                        text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                        rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
                    }).appendTo($list);
                }

                    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

                    $styledSelect.click(function(e) {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            $('div.select-styled.active').not(this).each(function(){
                                    $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.select-options').hide();
                            });
                            $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.select-options').toggle();
                    });

                    $listItems.click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
                    $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
                    $list.hide();
                    //console.log($this.val());
                });

                    $(document).click(function() {
                    $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
                    $list.hide();
                });
                });
```